# Nftables to do scalable MAC translation in NAPT-style

Tags: virtual-machine, bridge, nftables, mac-address

I'm a networking senior guy steadily diving more into Linux internals over last 5 years, grasping networking caps a lot, however just arriving at Netfilter domain and learning of nftables last 3-4 days to achieve what I need in my lab. I made an honest search for "MAC address translation/NAT" in this and ServerFault portals to land here.

I need to workaround some ESXI vSwitch lame VLAN mgmt capabilities when doing VM Linux bridging and **want to translate both ARP-hw_addr and real packets' MAC addresses to match MAC@ of VNIC assigned to Linux VM port**, as subject.

Full story shared on https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TBFYlO-n8G-inYO6cdnMnSEeYUP2Ch9vWNO_TwIxK9M/edit?usp=sharing

By reference, what **I can do is to statically translate** single host's MAC-related properties on opposite VM port/VLAN-dev (per my ref) by matching e.g. Y-side host IP@ and translating its MAC@ in both ARP and real Eth header to that of MAC A (on X-side) and vice versa in opposite direction:

```
table netdev mpls {
 chain input {
 type filter hook ingress device "mpls" priority filter; policy accept;
 arp daddr ip 172.16.100.189 arp daddr ether set 00:50:56:01:00:61 counter
 ether daddr 00:50:56:01:02:03 ether daddr set 00:50:56:01:00:61 counter accept
 }
 chain output {
 type filter hook egress device "mpls" priority filter; policy accept;
 arp saddr ip 172.16.100.189 arp saddr ether set 00:50:56:01:02:03 counter
 ether saddr 00:50:56:01:00:61 ether saddr set 00:50:56:01:02:03 counter accept
 }
}
```

**But I need to do this dynamically in scale**, to match on selected IP addresses and let NF do 2-way job on the fly. I hope other networking/virtualization fellows may find this useful to workaround some vSwitch insufficiences (subjective perspective).

**Question:** How to do this dynamically using ton of Netfilter caps working after netdev domain? If can't, only nf-queue call in bridge family with custom app could do this?

BR
Peter

Comment: Despite your link and schematic I have trouble understanding your design. Can't you forget using a Linux bridge, forget using nftables, and instead use Proxy ARP? This tool (packaged for example in Debian) could help manage this dynamically: http://www.hazard.maks.net/parprouted/ . Will limit applications relying on broadcast.

Comment: Also, there shouldn't be the need to consult an external link. You should put the schematic in the question (if your status prevents multiple pictures to be displayed, somebody else can edit the question to allow it), and possibly give additional layout description on how it's set up. Ideally the description should allow to reproduce a mockup setup (eg: even without an ESXi, it's possible to filter "non conforming" traffic). You should explain how there's a scalability issue. Eg, what prevents naively putting 50x this kind of lines? Is that because the addresses are not knows yet?

Comment: Hello A.B, thanks for your time and indeed much promising 1st reaction --> will test yet! Definitiely no need to rework my diagram, as it really matches what I want to achieve in my job with outlook to automate it in least code possible on both Linux TC VM and client (sw/hw device) sides. On a given subnet, to be able to pick host in order to mangle its OQS path, so to transition it from X side to Y side and to get rid of promiscous ESXI vnic port config. (external link is unrelated to demanded functionality).

Comment: Yes, that's a scalability concern you understand --> my selected host picks should work even in whichever sized VLAN/subnet.
So back to Proxy ARP app --> question is, what MAC address it uses, if own virtual or respective of any side conf'd (I see 2 in ref'd link, or even more bridged possible?). If the latter applies, I get the amazing solution. Yet I had an idea of kernel bridge interface doing Proxy ARP per possible ip config, with broadcast ARPs blocked on both X and Y sides to reach opposite side but again to make sure I can proxy with those MAC@ matching parent VM ports into vSwitch..

Comment: So more config to do compared to Proxy app your highlighted.

Comment: proxy arp (almost by definition) uses the interfaces' MAC addresses: what you're looking for.  Now I have no idea of the performance of parprouted within a /16 subnet: probably poor. To consider anything else I'd have to test it, but as the problem looks complex I'd be unable to reproduce it.

Comment: You really pointed it great by Proxy ARP feature, which I just shamefully missed :) but the problem is it indeed needs another IP addresses from my VLAN subnet, which I may not have. Because without that if was really announcing to both X and Y sides the proper MAC@, however it was not relaying traffic at all in between, though I enabled ip fwd and even proxy arp to see NEI and ROUTE tables populated! Morevover, this app sustained to run for some 5mins (per ps grep), then gets down... so back luck.

Comment: I also found that with original bridge the slave ports can enable proxy_arp opt as per doc, however even tables were not populated... the only way remains then nftables edit with more scalable script, but it will be just matter of luck...